# If-Else statement produces wrong result in R

Tags: r, if-statement, decode

I have a data frame called 'clean' that looks like this:

```
structure(list(X = 6:12, CollectorID = c(58302467L, 58302467L, 
57754564L, 58301689L, 58302467L, 58302467L, 57754564L), StartDate = structure(c(7L, 
6L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("10/5/14 1:49", "10/5/14 2:03", 
"10/5/14 2:06", "10/5/14 2:09", "10/5/14 2:25", "10/5/14 2:48", 
"10/5/14 3:06"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("X", "CollectorID", 
"StartDate"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

I want to translate the numeric values in CollectorID into names in a new field called 'Collector'. The code I'm using

```
if(clean$CollectorID==58302467){
  clean$Collector<-"Social Media"
} else if(clean$CollectorID==57754564){
    clean$Collector<-"Email"
} else {
  clean$Collector<-"Blog Post"  
}
```

produces the following warning message:

```
In if (clean$CollectorID == 58302467) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

I don't understand the warning, and my code also produces a wrong result; it sets all values in clean$Collector to "Blog Post".

Comment: Read `help("if")`.  Once you read all of that note the part in See Also where it suggests looking at `ifelse`.  With that said direct indexing would work fine here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ifelse()` if you want. foo is your data.

```
foo$Collector <- ifelse(foo$CollectorID == 58302467, "Social Media",
                      ifelse(foo$CollectorID == 57754564, "Email", "Blog Post"))

#   X CollectorID    StartDate    Collector
#1  6    58302467 10/5/14 3:06 Social Media
#2  7    58302467 10/5/14 2:48 Social Media
#3  8    57754564 10/5/14 2:25        Email
#4  9    58301689 10/5/14 2:06    Blog Post
#5 10    58302467 10/5/14 2:09 Social Media
#6 11    58302467 10/5/14 2:03 Social Media
#7 12    57754564 10/5/14 1:49        Email
```

Given @KFB's comment, you could do something like this. You create another data frame with CollectorID and Desired output (e.g., "Social Media"). Then, you could use `merge()` or `left_join()` in `dplyr`. Here is one with `merge()`

```
CollectorID <- c(58302467,57754564,58301689)
type <- c("Social Media", "Email", "Blog Post")
ana <- data.frame(CollectorID, type, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

merge(foo, ana, by = "CollectorID", all = TRUE)

#  CollectorID  X    StartDate         type
#1    57754564  8 10/5/14 2:25        Email
#2    57754564 12 10/5/14 1:49        Email
#3    58301689  9 10/5/14 2:06    Blog Post
#4    58302467  6 10/5/14 3:06 Social Media
#5    58302467  7 10/5/14 2:48 Social Media
#6    58302467 10 10/5/14 2:09 Social Media
#7    58302467 11 10/5/14 2:03 Social Media
```

Comment: Thanks @jazzurro, this works great. Curious to know whether ifelse would still be the best way to handle this problem if I had a much longer list of values to decode.

Comment: If this is the data frame you have, and if you do not mind overwriting CollectorID, you could do something like `foo[foo == 58302467] <- "Social Media"`

Comment: This method here may not be efficient if your data has million of lines, for example. Probably you will need to use various "join" functions in packages like data.table and dplyr.

Comment: I agree. I was not sure how large this data can be.

Answer (score 0):

'match' function can also be used here. Using @jazzurro's example:

```
> ana$type[match(foo$CollectorID, ana$CollectorID)]
[1] "Social Media" "Social Media" "Email"        "Blog Post"    "Social Media" "Social Media" "Email"       
> 
> foo$Collector = ana$type[match(foo$CollectorID, ana$CollectorID)]
> foo
   X CollectorID    StartDate    Collector
1  6    58302467 10/5/14 3:06 Social Media
2  7    58302467 10/5/14 2:48 Social Media
3  8    57754564 10/5/14 2:25        Email
4  9    58301689 10/5/14 2:06    Blog Post
5 10    58302467 10/5/14 2:09 Social Media
6 11    58302467 10/5/14 2:03 Social Media
7 12    57754564 10/5/14 1:49        Email
```